# Setting G Suite user properties with App Script and the Admin SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-app-maker

I'm trying to set a user's OU from an App Script inside App Maker. 
(`user` is a variable with an email address)

```
function getUser(user) {
  var x = AdminDirectory.Users.update(
    {
      orgUnitPath: "/",
      userKey: user,
    });
  console.log("function ran");
}
```

This code errors with:

```
Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only at getUser (ServerScripts:107)
Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only
at getUser (ServerScripts:107)
at getUser (ClientHandoff:21:21)
at TestMoveOU.Panel1.Button1.onClick:1:1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Looking at [the docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user), you only need to provide the properties you're changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#reference)** says the following:

> For detailed information on this service, see the reference documentation for the Admin SDK Directory API. Like all advanced services in Apps Script, the Admin SDK Directory service uses the same objects, methods, and parameters as the public API.

Therefore, we need to consult the **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update)** to get clarification on how to achieve this.

The method requires at least two parameters: that means that the the first parameter is a user object resource and the second parameter is the email address of the user: `AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource, userKey)`. So you need to do this:

```
function getUser(user) {
    var userResource = {
        orgUnitPath: "/"
    };
    var updated = AdminDirectory.Users.update(userResource, user);
    console.log(updated.primaryEmail);
}
```

So why do you need to specify the user email in the method when it is already being specified in the `userResource` object? Well, the email address in the `userResource` object would be the new value, in case you want to change the email address.

P.S. Perhaps you might wanna change the name of the function to something that is more of a match; `updateUser()` perhaps? I hope this helps!

Comment: This worked, and your explanation helped a lot - thanks!

Comment: For future readers: You'll need to change `orgUnitPath = "/"` to `orgUnitPath: "/"`

Comment: @IanHyzy I saw that... sorry. I just edited the answer to match the above comment.